# trying to transform the adapter.setViewBinder to a getview method in the overriden method of the adapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

So I have a function:

```
  adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.rating,cu,new String[]{"Title","Fav"}, new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.bt_rating},CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);   
      //added in last update
        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder(){
               /** Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view */
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){

                if(view.getId() == R.id.bt_rating){
                    String favorites=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Fav")).toString();                     
                    if(favorites.equals("Filled"))
                    {

                        ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {                       

                        ((CheckBox)view).setChecked(false); 
                    }
                    ((CheckBox)view).setTag(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))); 
                    //((CheckBox)view).setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
                    return true; //true because the data was bound to the view
                }

                return false;
            }

            });
```

because I have a listview with checkbox button and textview so I am telling the viewbinder to check if the checkbox value is filled (in the fav column in the databse) then it should check the checkbox and set it a tag so that I can call it later and work on it and if it's empty it will keep the checkbox unchecked.. and this is working fine but since I need to do other work on the data I am trying to create my own simplecursor adapter... and ovveride the getview() method and transform the previous work into the public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup vg)  function but don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

I saw this tutorial and it's amazing:

https://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

With this information, I completed my task.